# Multi Columns Combo Box for Swing

Tags: java, swing

currently, I am looking for a multi columns comb box components which can place in my Java Swing application.

Currently, I use combo box as auto complete drop down list as user is typing.

[image]

Is there any available GUI component, which enable me to have the following (multi collumns)? As you can see, there are 3 columns in the drop down list, as opposed to 1 column in the above example.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/08/multi-column-jcombobox.html) is a downloadable solution with two columns.

There are other candidates [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=57&threadID=707295) and [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/340213/GUI/java/Multiple-Columns-JCombobox) but you need to write your own renderer.