# Show full string of JCombobox's Item where combobox's width is smaller than String

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have one `JComboBox` on my screen. Have restricted it's width as I want to show that combobox in specific area only. Now If that combobox contains data or String longer than `JComboBox`'s width, user can't view full string of that item. Is there any way to show full String once use click on that combobox. But combobox's width is fixed only.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As far as I know, the width of the popup of the combobox is always the same as the width of the combobox itself. Is a tooltip an option ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer and Robin: Tooltip may be the option, but any way to show dropdown list in full width?

Comment: There's a few ways I've seen it done, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956003/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-a-jcombobox-dropdown-list) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969757/how-to-have-jcombobox-drop-down-list-which-is-wider-than-the-jcombobox-itself) for some suggestions

Comment: @MadProgrammer the second trick (forcing the prefSize of the scrollPane) no longer works since 6u26 - what's left is Santhosh's trick (faking the combo's width) used in the first

Comment: @kleopatra I just whacked the first couple of links I found, I knew that one of the hacks didn't work any more, but seen as I don't use any of them, I wasn't sure which one :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer my problem solved by using Santhosh Kumar's trick. Just while assigning width to dimention, I am calculating max string length and multiply with 7..... Thank you and Santosh too..... :)

Comment: *"roblem solved"*  You should write that up as an answer & accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved. Thanks to MadProgrammer who suggest me [How can I change the width of a JComboBox dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956003/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-a-jcombobox-dropdown-list) link from where I got Santosh Kumar's blog.
Here is that link

http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/make_jcombobox_popup_wide_enough

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Combo Box Width](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/) for a solution that allows you to control the width as well as location of the popup (above/below).

Comment: @kleopatra, what makes one "trick" acceptable and other not? I think I got the idea of the original trick from you. The class was updated to work with JDK7. It also supports more then just a wide popup which some people may want. I agree it can be sub optimal to use tricks of any kind because they can break in the next version, but even base code can break in the next version.

Comment: guilty of not trying yours, just skimmed the code and judged by setPref/max in the listener, overlooked the invokeLater ;-) works fine, +1!